# Updating Records through Codeigniter |

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, crud

I have created a Table to insert the data of Books, the values of which are taken from a form. Now I wanted to perform the CRUD operations. But I was having problems with updating the data. Instead of replacing the old data, the entered data is taken as a new entry. What must I do?

What I did was as follows :

> > I have created a link on the homepage which redirects to a page where it shows the list of books and their details which can be entered through another link for adding books. The Book_ID has been taken as the Primary Key for the library table.
> >
> > Now in the page where it shows the list, I have added an "EDIT" and a "DELETE" button. The Delete button works fine as the syntax is direct and simple. But for the Edit Button, which redirects to the Add Books Page but the form is autofilled with the particular data using $Book_ID=$B$this->->uri->segments[3]; which I have sent to the base_model to retrieve data from that particular row with that particular Book_ID.
> >
> > Now the problem am having is that after editing the data, I have put a tag  ...but am not pretty much sure whether I have to do this..I was told that it must be there. But the fact that I actually must send the Book_ID back to the controller and that should be sent to the model where it uses that particular id to update data in that row. Am really confused!

Comment: What's the problem getting the book_id again in your controller after update?

Comment: Show some code so we can help you\.

Comment: you write wrong parameter in uri it is $this->uri->segment(3)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to sent back `book_id` to `update records`.You can do this in this way

**Your controller**

```
`public function update_books($book_id)
{
   $data=$this->Your_model_name->book_data($book_id);
   if($data)
   {
       'your success message';
   }
    else
   {
       'Your error message';
   }
}
`
```

and now **in model**

```
`
public function book_data($book_id)
{
   $this->db->where('id',$book_id);
  if( $this->db->update('TABLE_NAME',array('field_name'=>$this->input->post('post_variable_name'))))
    return true;
  else
     return false;

}
`
```

this is a simple way to update your records.

Answer (score 0):

send your data as array and id of record you want to update it.

your controller

```
$form_data = array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                   'email'=>$this->input->('email')
                  );
$this->crud_model->update($form_data,$id);
```

your model:

```
function update($data,$id)
{
   $this->db->trans_start();
   $this->db->where('id',$id);
   $this->db->update('yourtablename',$data);
   $this->db->trans_complete();
   return TRUE;
}
```

do it and it will work.